# What is @object in **ELF**

Tags: x86-64, reverse-engineering, elf

_thread int errno;

int get_errno() { return errno; }

And when i am disassembling it i am getting
**for x86**

```
  .globl     errno
  .section  .tbss,"awT",@nobits
  .align    4
  .type     errno, @object
  .size     errno, 4
  errno:
  .zero     4
   movl     %fs:errno@tpoff, %eax
```

What does     <**.type errno , @object indicate here**>

Please send a link of any valid document if you have

Answer (score 2):

`.type errno, @object` sets the symbol type. It is represented in ELF as part of the `st_info` field in the `Elf32_Sym` or `Elf64_Sym` struct. `<elf.h>` uses `STT_*` constants for these symbols, and `@object` corresponds to `STT_OBJECT`. The constant values can be extracted from the `st_info` field using the `ELF32_ST_TYPE` and `ELF64_ST_TYPE` macros.

In the ELF specification, this is described in the [Symbol Table](http://www.sco.com/developers/gabi/latest/ch4.symtab.html) chapter.